# Moving static files into docker container

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose

I would like to create a Dockerfile that builds the static files for a react application and copy it into another image.

When I run `docker-compose up` with the files below, I find that the nginx container doesn't have the files I want in `/config/www`. Any ideas what I'm missing?

#### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  api:
    build:
      context: ./api
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-prod
    volumes:
      - ./db:/usr/src/app/db
    ports:
      - 5000
    environment:
      - FLASK_ENV=production
      - EMAIL_USERNAME=${EMAIL_USERNAME}
      - EMAIL_PASSWORD=${EMAIL_PASSWORD}
      - JWT_SECRET_KEY=${JWT_SECRET_KEY}
      - JWT_COOKIE_DOMAIN=${JWT_COOKIE_DOMAIN}
      - ADMIN_USERNAME=${ADMIN_USERNAME}
      - ADMIN_PASSWORD=${ADMIN_PASSWORD}

  # client:
  #   build:
  #     context: ./client
  #     dockerfile: Dockerfile-prod
  #   volumes:
  #     - react:/usr/src/app/build
  #   environment:
  #     - NODE_ENV=production

  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-prod
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      # - react:/config/www
      - ./nginx/prod.conf:/config/nginx/site-confs/default
    environment:
      - PUID=1050
      - PGID=1050
      - URL=${JWT_COOKIE_DOMAIN}
      - TZ=Australia/Sydney
    depends_on:
      - api

# volumes:
#   react:
```

#### Dockerfile-prod

```
FROM node:10.16.0-alpine AS build

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

ADD client /usr/src/app
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

FROM linuxserver/letsencrypt
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/build /config/www
```

#### build output

```
Step 7/9 : RUN npm run build
 ---> Running in 555e104b262d
> learning@1.3.0 build /usr/src/app
> react-scripts build
Creating an optimized production build...
Compiled successfully.
File sizes after gzip:
  150.58 KB (-11.48 KB)  build/static/js/2.c3a02695.chunk.js
  18.89 KB (-2.06 KB)    build/static/js/main.7370b4bd.chunk.js
  18.7 KB (-128 B)       build/static/css/2.0ce8856a.chunk.css
  17.2 KB (-807 B)       build/static/css/main.7a2495bd.chunk.css
  762 B                  build/static/js/runtime~main.a8a9905a.js
The project was built assuming it is hosted at the server root.
You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.
For example, add this to build it for GitHub Pages:
  "homepage" : "http://myname.github.io/myapp",
The build folder is ready to be deployed.
You may serve it with a static server:
  npm install -g serve
  serve -s build
Find out more about deployment here:
  https://********
Removing intermediate container 555e104b262d
 ---> 56f493772583
Step 8/9 : FROM linuxserver/letsencrypt
 ---> 17f7eabbfdf4
Step 9/9 : COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/build /config/www
 ---> e4f875f96fd3
Successfully built e4f875f96fd3
Successfully tagged learning_nginx:latest
```

Comment: can you share the docker file for the nginx ?

Comment: @Al-waleedShihadeh
`Dockerfile-prod` in the OP is the dockerfile for nginx. Basically, I'm trying to build the html/js files and placing them into this [image](https://github.com/linuxserver/docker-letsencrypt)

Comment: try to create the folder ` /config/www` before the copy

Comment: can you share the build output ?

Comment: @Al-waleedShihadeh updated the OP with the relevant build output. The image already has `/config/www` with a default `index.html` inside.

Comment: @trivial_tasks Your docker-files look alright. Try re-creating the images `docker-compose up --force-recreate`

Comment: @ManishRaj I'm not sure what I did but it suddenly worked so I suppose the config file wasn't the issue... Will keep that command in mind for the future.